# align radio button one below the other

Tags: html, css, css-float

How do i have the radio button show one below the other like this?

```
                 Sex                 (button)Male
                                     (button) Female
```

Whatever i do, i get like this

```
                   Sex                 (button)Male
                   (button) Female
```

how do i do the margin left of the second radio button so that it is right below the first one?

```
            <label for="Sex">Sex:</label>
            <asp:RadioButton ID="male" runat="server" GroupName="gender" 
                    Text="Male"/>
            <br/>

            <asp:RadioButton ID="female" runat="server" GroupName="gender" Text="Female"/>
```

Comment: OT: Your HTML is incorrect, the label is not pointing to anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either group the items in side-by-side `div`s, or add additional spacing to align the second item.

floated divs:

```
<div style="float: left;">
       <span>Sex:</label>
</div>
<div style="float: left;">
    <asp:RadioButton ID="male" runat="server" GroupName="gender" Text="Male"/>
    <br/>
    <asp:RadioButton ID="female" runat="server" GroupName="gender" Text="Female"/>        
</div>
<div style="clear: both"></div>
```

or with padding:

```
<style>
    .radioButtonPadding {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 45px;
    }
</style>

<span class="radioButtonPadding">Sex:</label>
<asp:RadioButton ID="male" runat="server" GroupName="gender" Text="Male"/>
<br/>
<span class="radioButtonPadding">&nbsp;</label>
<asp:RadioButton ID="female" runat="server" GroupName="gender" Text="Female"/>
```

You can also do it as a [`RadioButtonList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist.aspx)

```
<style>
    .genderLabel {
        float: left;
        display: block;
    }
    .genderList {
        float: left;
    }
    .clear {
        clear: both;
    }
</style>

<asp:Label id="genderLabel" runat="server" CssClass="genderLabel"       
    Text="Sex:" AssociatedControlID="genderList"/>
<asp:RadioButtonList id="genderList" runat="server" CssClass="genderList">
   <asp:ListItem>Male</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem>Female</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. i was able to use radio button list and get it working. Since i had some span tags before that, i was not able to clear using div (your last line), but i was able to use <br style="clear:both"/> to clear the elements.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/fUvZR/1/

You'll need a container `div` with a set width, and then two `div`'s inside of it floated to the sides.

Comment: since i had some span tags contained in the code section, i was not able to use the div method. i could only use the radiobuttonlist.

Answer (score 0):

Use a RadioButtonList

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1"
    runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CausesValidation="True" 
    onselectedindexchanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True">male</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>female</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a RadioButtonList control and simply set the RepeatDirection property to Horizontal:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist.repeatdirection.aspx