# How can I align radio buttons on html form?

Tags: c#, html, css

I'm trying to get these radio buttons aligned so they are side by side in the containing div. How can I accomplish this.

```
 <div class="form-field">
      @Html.Label("Gender")
      <span>Male @Html.RadioButton("gender", "Male")</span>
      <span>Female @Html.RadioButton("gender", "Female")</span>
      <span>Unkown @Html.RadioButton("gender", "Unknown")</span>
 </div>
```

Output should be inline not stacked on each other. Ie8

Comment: can you show the CSS of the form-field and the spans using FireBug or some other tool? If i paste it inside a clean MVC3 project in the index they're all next to eachother

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think people are over complicating the answer here. If you want a series of radio buttons lined up simply wrap your inputs in label elements:

```
<div class="form-field">
<label><input type="radio" name="lump">Lump</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="stump">Stump</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="bump">Bump</label>
</div>
```

This will line the radio buttons one next to the other. If you want them running straight up and down in your CSS add display:block to your label elements. This works down to IE7. And here's the relevant section of the HTML spec: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#the-label-element.

So for your code, this should work:

```
<div class="form-field">
      @Html.Label("Gender")
      <label>Male @Html.RadioButton("gender", "Male")</label>
      <label>Female @Html.RadioButton("gender", "Female")</label>
      <label>Unkown @Html.RadioButton("gender", "Unknown")</label>
 </div>
```

And the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kdUAS/

Answer (score 1):

I have created a div and the a table witrh in that, this allows me to indicate the radio button as one of the table data.
below is the sample code of that, you can try:

```
    <div>
    <table class="textfont" style="width:100%">
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><asp:RadioButton ID="" runat="server" Text="" AutoPostBack="True" /></td>
    <td><asp:RadioButton ID="" runat="server" Text="" AutoPostBack="True" /></td>
    </tr> 
    </table>
    </div>
```

Tell me if there is a problem.

Comment: You need a closing `</table>` tag before the closing `</div>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either group the items in side-by-side divs, or add additional spacing to align the second item.

The following link will be useful for you

[align radio button one below the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315570/align-radio-button-one-below-the-other)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with C# much, but it's pretty simple using CSS:

`.form-field span { display:inline-block; margin-right:10px; }`

Here's my [**JSFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/josh_max/ZpPTP/).

**//edit**

Since I'm not familiar with C#, I'm not sure if your code will make it this way in the end, but it's good practice to put the radio buttons *before* your label. In this case,

**Ο** Male     **Ο** Female     **Ο** Unknown

As I said, though, I'm not familiar enough with C# to know, but thought I'd offer my advice for UI at least:)